# Error al querer actualizar tabla en oracle 10g: "ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified"

Tags: oracle

Tengo un pequeño problema con mi base de datos. Nos conectamos varios usuarios, hace un momento estaba yo trabajando sobre ella, pero me quede sin conexión. Justo cuando le di commit, al actualizar un registro, después me conecte de nuevo, pero no estaba la actualización de mi registro. Entonces intente actualizarlo pero, para sorpresa mía, obtuve el siguiente error:

> ```
> ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified
> ```

Que investigando un poco se refiere a que se quedó bloqueada la tabla, o algo por el estilo. Me puse a investigar [aquí](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2552670), [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075738/ora-00054-resource-busy-and-acquire-with-nowait-specified), y en otros lugares más que visité para dar con la respuesta, pero hasta el momento no he podido dar con ella.

¿Saben de alguna forma de que no me salga ese error?
Aclaro, solo es sobre esa tabla y sobre ese registro en especifico.

Comment: Hola @5frags. Por favor presta atención al generar nuevas etiquetas. La etiqueta `[bd]` no tiene ningún sentido que la crees, más que ya existe la etiqueta [tag:base-de-datos], aunque ni siquiera aplica para esta pregunta. Más información en [¿Qué son las etiquetas, y cómo debo usarlas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero paso1:

```
select object_name, s.sid, s.serial#, p.spid 
from v$locked_object l, dba_objects o, v$session s, v$process p
where l.object_id = o.object_id and l.session_id = s.sid and s.paddr = p.addr;
```

Segundo paso:

```
alter system kill session `'sid,serial#';--sid` y`serial#` Se obtienen en el paso 1.
```

[Mayor info](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/killing-oracle-sessions)

Comment: El object_name es mi tabla bloqueada?

Comment: Gracias, listo.

Comment: Por nada, en ocasiones llega a pasar que incluso  no permite matar la tarea de ser asì, se identifica el sid y se finaliza la tarea desde windows.